# While sending mail by Nodemailer I am getting error of Invalid login

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, nodemailer

I was trying to send mail by using nodejs nodemailer by using this code

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    requireTLS: true,
  auth: {
    user: 'mymail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'mypassword'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'mymail@gmail.com',
  to: 'tosendmail@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

and i got the error given below:

```
    { Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials c124-v6sm6149345pfa.119 - gsmtp
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/home/rajat/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:606:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/home/rajat/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1335:34)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (/home/rajat/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:366:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/home/rajat/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:762:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (/home/rajat/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:558:14)
    at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (/home/rajat/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:510:47)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials c124-v6sm6149345pfa.119 - gsmtp',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN' }
```

while i got the right way to send email by nodejs by [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478293/username-and-password-not-accepted-when-using-nodemailer/45479968)

and my code given below by using above reference:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    requireTLS: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'mymail@gmail.com',
        pass: 'mypassword'
    }
});

let mailOptions = {
    from: 'mymail@gmail.com',
    to: 'tosendmail@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Test',
    text: 'Hello World!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error.message);
    }
    console.log('success');
});
```

i got  message of success in this.

Now i want to ask both the above code are approximately similar then what is the problem with my first code . 
I tried to make first one work by doing some minor changes but was unable to do so .What can i do to make first one work .

Comment: Have you configured SMTP access on gmail? or you don't any idea about that?

Comment: @JanithKasun i think i have configured smtp access on gmail if you are referring to allowing access to less secure apps on gmail as the second code is working fine for me . However i am novice and started using nodejs recently so please explain if i am doing wrong .