# NodeMailer - Username and Password not accepted

Tags: javascript, express, gmail, nodemailer

I am getting this in postman -

```
{
     "code": "EAUTH",
     "response": "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n535 5.7.8  
                  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials x7- 
                  20020aa784c7000000b005058d220b37sm21945855pfn.64 - gsmtp",
     "responseCode": 535,
     "command": "AUTH PLAIN"
}
```

`Email And password not accepted` , I have already gone through this [question](https://I%20am%20getting%20this%20error%20-%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22code%22:%20%22EAUTH%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22response%22:%20%22535-5.7.8%20Username%20and%20Password%20not%20accepted.%20Learn%20more%20at%5Cn535%205.7.8%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials%20x7-%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2020020aa784c7000000b005058d220b37sm21945855pfn.64%20-%20gsmtp%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22responseCode%22:%20535,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22command%22:%20%22AUTH%20PLAIN%22%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%60Email%20And%20password%20not%20accepted%60%20,%20I%20have%20already%20gone%20through%20this%20%5Bquestion%5D%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478293/username-and-password-not-accepted-when-using-nodemailer), and tried possible way to resolve this problem, but nothing worked out.

nodemailer code section -

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
   host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
   port: 587,
   secure: false,
   auth: {
     user: 'mygmail@gmail.com',
     pass: 'mypassword'
   }
})

const info = await transporter.sendMail({
       from: 'mygmail@gmail.com',
       to: "person@gmail.com",
       subject: "subject",
       text: "text",
       html: `<h1> hello </h1>`
})
```

I have tried -

- generate an app-specific password and use that in place of your actual password.
- enabled the captcha ([link](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha))
- enabled the IMAP setting in gmail->setting->Forwarding and POP/IMAP

I Read this - [less secure app and google account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en#zippy=)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- First, You need to use a valid Gmail account with your credentials.
- You need to allow less secure apps from your google account to send emails. Through this link. [Allow less secure apps From your Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

---

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const sendEmail = async () => {
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: 'gmail',
auth: {
  user: 'sender gmail',
  pass: 'sender password',
  },
});

const options = {
from: 'sender gmail',
to: 'receiver gmail',
subject: 'subject',
text: 'text',
};

await transporter.sendMail(options);
}; 

module.exports = sendEmail;
```

Comment: can you explain your code

Comment: [Less secure apps & your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) are getting shut down May 2022 are you sure its a good idea to recomend using it?

Answer (score 1):

You can not login to the smtp server using a login and password anymore.  You could try using an apps password but as [Less secure apps & your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)  is being removed shortly this is probably not the best option.

[image]

I recommend looking into [Xoauth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol) this way you can authorize the user rather than relying upon their password.  I would try adapting [javascript-implicit-flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow) to see if this will work.

Comment: @DalmTo sir, thank you to introduce me with these terms `Xoauth2` and `javascript-implicit-flow`, I will learn more about these.