# How to send email using nodemailer and gmail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, gmail-api, nodemailer

I have created a contact form to send emails to client when form submitted but i keep getting  credentials error when i submit the form. I am using react for this project. My sendemail.js file and server file are in the root directory along with .env file. although contact form is in component directory. The actual credentials are in env file.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const sendEmail = async (formData) => {
  // Create a transporter using your email service provider's settings
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: process.env.REACT_APP_SMTP_USER, // Ensure these are set in your .env
      pass: process.env.REACT_APP_SMTP_PASSWORD, // App-Specific Password for Gmail
    }
  });

  // Setup email data
  const mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.REACT_APP_SMTP_USER, // Match this with the SMTP_USER
    to: formData.email,
    subject: formData.subject,
    text: `Name: ${formData.name}\nEmail: ${formData.email}\nMessage: ${formData.message}`,
  };

  // Attempt to send the email
  try {
    const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending email:', error);
    throw error; // Consider handling this more gracefully
  }
};

module.exports = sendEmail;
```

```
const express = require('express');
const sendEmail = require('./sendEmail');

const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const allowedOrigins = ['https://lashesbyjess.net', 'http://localhost:3000'];

app.use(cors({
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (!origin || allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
    }
  }
}));


app.use(express.json());



app.post('/api/send-email', async (req, res) => {
  const formData = req.body;

  try {

    await sendEmail(formData);
    res.status(200).send('Email sent successfully');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending email:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

what I have tried:

1. changing credentials
2. using app authenticator code from google.
3. disabling 2factor authentication code and using password instead in .env file.

originally the code worked before I ran the build. realized i needed to refactor code so it could be connected to any server not just local and thats when everything started to change.

Please any help would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance!

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478293/username-and-password-not-accepted-when-using-nodemailer